# Correct memory management in closures

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have method with closure.

It works like this

```
func ping() -> pingProtocol {
    let factory = pingFactory()
    let ping = factory.getPing() // returns pingProtocol conforming instance, for example "PingService"
    return ping
}

func performPing(success: @escaping () -> (), fail: @escaping () -> ()) {
    ping().status { (ready, response) in
        if ready {
            success()
        } else {
            fail()
        }
    }
}
```

Realisation of ping is abstraction over Alamofire.

```
class PingService {

func status(completion: @escaping (Bool, ServiceResponse) -> Void) {
    doSimpleRequest(endPoint: "/api/get_state/", param: [:], completion: completion)
}     

func doSimpleRequest(endPoint: String, param: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Bool, ServiceResponse) -> Void) {
        APIManager.shared.postRequest(mode: APIMode.Service, endPoint: endPoint, parameters: param) { [weak self] (response, error) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let serviceResponse = ServiceResponse(dict: response)
            if error != nil {
                completion(false, serviceResponse)
                return
            }

            completion(true, serviceResponse)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that with `weak self` guard in self is always triggers. If I use `unowned`, I get crash. If I dont use `weak` or `unowned` it works fine.

The ping method itself lives in viewmodel of controller, and controller stays on screen when completion block is needed to be executed, so the problem is in deallocation of `ping` instance, not in viewmodel thats holds it.

If I use capture list I dont get desired behavior, but If I do I suspect that I get memory leak.

What is best practice here ?

Comment: You "suspect" that you get a memory leak, but have you actually tested it to see if you get a memory leak?

Comment: Use unowned if you are 100% sure you wont get nil values else it will crash.